# consume flask data and display in tabulator

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, tabulator

I am trying to display the following data I am getting from my flask end point into [tabulator](http://tabulator.info/)
here is my html body.

```html
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
<iframe id="invisible" name="invisible" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<span class="labela successa" id="header"><b>tabledata</b></span><br>
<h3></h3>
<form target="invisible" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/test" style="margin:10px;margin-bottom: 300px;" method="post">
 <span class="label success" id="select_d">Select custom period</span>
 
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="" />
<!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" value="Submit"> -->
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    var sd = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + " 00:00"
    var ed = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + " 23:59"
    console.log(sd)
    console.log(ed)
    var params = {};
    params.start = sd;
    params.end = ed;
    $.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test', params).done(function (data) {
    // callback
});
  });
});

</script>

<!---- Table here -start-->
<div id="example-table"></div>

<script>
 var tabledata = $("#example-table").tabulator("setData", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test");
 var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
  data:tabledata, //assign data to table
  layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  columns:[ //Define Table Columns
    {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
    {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
  ],
  rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
  },
});

</script>

<!---- Table here -end-->
</body>
```

here is my flask endpoint which returns the data in json format.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request,json
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from jira import JIRA
import re
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():

  return render_template("table.html")

@app.route('/test',methods=['GET','POST'])
def tabledata():
  start_date = request.form['start']
  end_date = request.form['end']
  options = {'server': 'abc.com', 'verify': False}
  jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('username', 'Password'))
  issues= jira.search_issues('project="LSDF" AND issuetype = JKL AND created >="'+start_date+'" AND created <="'+end_date+'"', maxResults=100)
  issuelist = []
  for issue_names in issues:
    issuelist.append(issue_names.key)
  print(issuelist)
  data = []
  for ticket in issuelist:
    jiraissue = jira.issue(ticket)
    data.append({'age_id': jiraissue.key, 'scape':jiraissue.fields.customfield_18242[0].fields.summary, 'Description': jiraissue.fields.summary, 'incident_start': jiraissue.fields.customfield_14040})
  print (data)
  
  return json.dumps(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to capture this data into the Tabulator plugin that I have used above in the HTML body, right now I am not sure how can I achieve this as there are no clear instructions, can anyone help here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabulators Ajax documentation specifies the format that the data needs to be returned in, in order for Tabulator to process it. Checkout the [Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/data#ajax-response) for full details.

Essentially your ajax response must return a JSON encoded array of row objects, with each object in the array representing a row of data. Eg:

```js
[
    {"id":1, "name":"bob", "age":"23"},
    {"id":2, "name":"jim", "age":"45"},
    {"id":3, "name":"steve", "age":"32"}
]
```

If you cant return the data in that format, then you can use the ***ajaxResponse*** callback to process the response and convert it into that format before it is passed into the table.

Full details of all of this can be found in the [Ajax Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/data#ajax)

#### Update - passing data into the table

The issue with loading in data is because you are calling the ***setData*** function before event creating the table:

```js
$("#example-table").tabulator("setData", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test");
```

This function does not return data, it tells tabulator to go and retrieve it, so your above option does nothing.

If you only need to load the data when the table is first loaded then the best approach is to not use ***setData*** or the ***data*** property at all. Instead use the ***ajaxURL*** property in the table constructor object and pass the url to it

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://www.getmydata.com/now",
    ....//other table setup options
});
```

Full details of all of this can be found in the first paragraph of the documentation of loading data in using ajax, see the [Ajax Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/data#ajax)

Comment: But how do I send the data to table